# Drawing graph in latex

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I would like to make the following drawing in latex but I don't know how.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I did not downvote this, but please note that this site requires you to ask specific questions, which in the case of graphics and diagrams almost always means that you should present some code that shows what you tried so far and where you got stuck, preferably by providing a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 7):

Using Ti*k*Z and some loops you could do:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \x using {pow(2,\i-1)}] in {1,...,4} {
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\x} {
            \draw ({4-8*\j/\x},0) -- ++({4/\x},{4/\x}) -- ++({4/\x},{-4/\x});
        }
    }

    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) (-5,0) -- (5,0);

    \node[right] at (0,4) {$+1$};
    \node[below] at (-4,0) {$-1$};
    \node[below] at (4,0) {$+1$};

    \foreach \k [evaluate = \k as \y using {pow(2,2-\k)},
                 evaluate = \k as \z using {int(pow(2,\k))})] in {1,...,3} {
        \draw[densely dotted] (-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
        \node[left] at (-4,\y) {$u = \frac{1}{\z}$};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could build upon this and make it more flexible so that you can change 4 to 5 (or even higher numbers) and get a larger diagram:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\tiny

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{5}

    \foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \x using {pow(2,\i-1)}] in {1,...,\d} {
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\x} {
            \draw ({\d-2*\d*\j/\x},0) -- ++({\d/\x},{\d/\x}) -- ++({\d/\x},{-\d/\x});
        }
    }

    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,{\d+0.5}) ({-\d-1},0) -- ({\d+1},0);

    \node[right] at (0,{\d}) {$+1$};
    \node[below] at ({-\d},0) {$-1$};
    \node[below] at ({\d},0) {$+1$};

    \foreach \k [evaluate = \k as \y using {\d/2/pow(2,\k-2)},
                 evaluate = \k as \z using {int(pow(2,\k-1))})] in {2,...,\d} {
        \draw[densely dotted] ({-\d},\y) -- ({\d},\y);
        \node[left] at ({-\d},\y) {$u = \frac{1}{\z}$};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously not everybody likes this approach ... feel free to post another solution then ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'm learning how to use tikZ. Thank you one more time!